# sexy bookmark plugin breaks my site in ie6

Tags: wordpress, plugins, internet-explorer-6

The sexy bookmark plugin is breaking my wordpress site in ie6. It's showing some error message. Is there any way that i can disable the plugin if ie6 is detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this conditional comment to handle ie6 issues

```
<!--[if IE 6]><![endif]-->
```

[more informations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: it is not about css only..you can disable the entire JS code if the client browser is IE6 , isn't this what you want ?

Comment: Actually the javascript is added by a plugin. Is there any way to disable a plugin detecting the browser.